# WhereNotIn In Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have issue with `whereNotIn` in laravel 4 , i need to get that not in from array of ids as bellow

```
 $studAttend  = StudentAttendees::select('subject_schedule_id')->distinct()->get();

$Check  = SubjectSchedule::whereNotIn('id', array($studAttend))->get();
```

Also I tried to change my code to loop over `$studAttend` as bellow

```
$studAttendArray = array();

foreach ($studAttend as $stdAtt)
{
    $studAttendArray [] = $stdAtt ; 
}
```

To become

```
$Check  = SubjectSchedule::whereNotIn('id', $studAttendArray)->get();
```

The issue that the result of `$Check` variable return null `[]` but when i use the following manual code the result if `$Check` return the row that i need it

```
$Check  = SubjectSchedule::whereNotIn('id', array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ))->get();
```

**Note** the above numbers inside the array they is the same result of `$studAttend` OR `$stuAttendArray` .

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved It just by using `toArray()` as bellow

```
$Check  = SubjectSchedule::whereNotIn('id', $studAttend->toArray());
```

Now not return `[]`

Answer (score 1):

The functionality looks fine, you just need to make sure you're passing in the correct array.

This code should work a little easier:

```
// lists will return an actual array with just the field specified as the values.
// array_unique will make sure the values are unique.
$studAttend = array_unique(StudentAttendees::lists('subject_schedule_id'));

// pass the array to your next query
$Check = SubjectSchedule::whereNotIn('id', $studAttend)->get();
```

Comment: Good answer , i found another way it's working well also, you can check my answer .

Answer (score 0):

you can use where not like this

```
$Check  = SubjectSchedule::whereIn('id', '!=', $studAttendArray)->get();
```

Comment: @user3621494 You can't compare against an array like that. You need to use `whereIn()` or `whereNotIn()`.